# retrieve data in angular2 with firebase

Tags: firebase, angular

i tried to retrieve data from firebase with angular2 today without success, i can console log data and see object, but for reusing them i have undefined in the console, maybe an issue with synchronous  and asynchronous data, what kind of solution i have to retrieve these data  with angular2?

thank you

```js
  read(){
    this.publicationUrl  = "https://FBURL/publication";
    this.PublicationRef = new Firebase(this.publicationUrl);
    this.PublicationRef.on("child_added", function(snapshot){
      this.publication = snapshot.val();
      console.log(this.publication)

    })
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you set data to the wrong `this` object. Use [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to preserve lexical scope:

```js
read() {
    this.publicationUrl  = "https://FBURL/publication";
    this.PublicationRef = new Firebase(this.publicationUrl);
    this.PublicationRef.on("child_added", snapshot => {
        this.publication = snapshot.val();
        console.log(this.publication);
    });
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for your answer,
 i can console.log datas , and see objects but cannot use them because they are undifined , when i ngfor the datas with json pipe i can see them...
i build and custom pipe  to transform value and args to return what i want , i have this error 

Cannot convert undefined or null to object